# Migrating from class component to functional component, setState as useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there any easy way of setting state variables as shown below when migrating from RCC to RFC?

So in my RCC i have something like that.

```
changeState(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
    })
}
```

Is it possible to write it in a RFC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState({});
const changeState = useCallback((e) => {
    setState(oldState => ({ ...oldState, [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value }))
}, [])
```

Comment: although it makes sense, seems like my website freezes when i start typing to the input element i use changeState()..

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't add the deps [] at the end.. Now seems to be fine

Answer (score 0):

I have a handleChange function that takes in a set function as arguments and bundle it as it’s own custom hook.

```
handleChange = (setFunction, e) => {
  setFunction(e.target.value)
}
```

Then in your component you can use something like

```
event => handleChange(setName, event)
```